# How to increment MongoDB document object fields inside an array

Tags: mongodb, nosql

This is the format of my document:

```
{
    _id: some id,
    name: 'some name',
    versions: []
}
```

In the `versions` field I store objects like `{v: '2.5', count: 5}` where `count` holds the number of times a version is in used.

What is the simplest way to do the following?

1. Insert a new object inside the `versions` array if it doesn't exist
2. Ff a particular version exists inside the `versions` array then increment its `count`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Simplest** way being should be,

```
db.collection.update({versions.v:'some_version'},{"$inc":{"versions.$.count":1}});
```

This will increment your count if version is exist, but as MongoDB documentation says, `$` operator cannot be mixed with upsert, so above query won't result in insert if `{versions.v:'some_version'}` fails.

> The positional operator cannot be combined with an upsert since it
>   requires a matching array element. If your update results in an insert
>   then the "$" will literally be used as the field name.

Below are JIRA tickets for supporting upsert with $. You can vote and watch these issue.

[Upsert with $-positional operator can create bad documents](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4713)

[Support $ positional operator with an upsert](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3326)