# upserting an array with $inc in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to create a query that will increment a counter in an object inside an array, but in case the object does not exist - it will be created (upsering)

**example:**

```
{
'_id' : 'someId',
someArray : [..,{'name':'a', 'count':234},..],
...
}
```

how will an upsert of the object **{'name' : 'b'}** will look like?

I'm using Node.js for the server side if that matter.

Comment: My advice: change your database structure, i.e. make `someArray` a seperate collection with reference to your main collection.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @freakish.

I did changed my structure - but still stayed with one collection. instead of an array I used an object:

```
someObject : {'a':234, 'b':1}...
```

I did it this way because I understand there is a problem to upsert  an array element with the $inc property:
[How to increment MongoDB document object fields inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11184079/how-to-increment-object-fields-inside-an-array-using-mongodb)

this solution works for me since I do not expect more than 100 elements in this object